# Can we remove minutes selection popup from Kartik datetime picker widget in yii2?

Tags: php, yii2, datetimepicker, kartik-v

I am working in yii2. I am using kartik datetimepicker widget. I want to remove minutes selection popup from datetimepicker.

Here is my code for datetimepicker pugin:

```
    <?php
     echo $form->field($model, 'pick_date')->label(false)->widget(kartik\datetime\DateTimePicker::classname(), [
               'options' => ['placeholder' => 'Enter pickup date time ...'],
               'readonly' => true,
               'pluginOptions' => [
               'autoclose' => true,
               'format' => 'yyyy/mm/dd HH:ii P'
              ]
           ]);
  ?>
```

From above code i am getting datetimepicker but i want to remove minutes selection popup

[image]

Any property or any way to skip this step ?

**Thank You**

Answer (score 2):

Update answer:

In `pluginOptions` array add option `minView => 1`

Comment: But I want to hour like 5:00 I just dont want minutes selection